# Could US president start and expect to survive a global nuclear war?

Tags: science-based, warfare, politics, post-apocalypse, law

Consider the following, modern-day scenario:

- A relative madman is elected as US president
- The US president [can irreversibly launch nuclear weapons under 60 minutes without oversight by congress, courts, or state governments for any reason](http://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2016/06/2016-donald-trump-nuclear-weapons-missiles-nukes-button-launch-foreign-policy-213955)
- The president understands [the mutually ensured destruction (MAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction) doctrine and its criticisms
- The president learns of a method where he, his immediate family, and select few loyal deputies could start and survive a global nuclear exchange (e.g. US vs Russia/China) and subsequent climate/economic disaster, while neutralizing the rival governments (and a large segment of world's population).
- This method allows for establishing a new, post-nuclear-exchange government, of which, the president and his family/deputies would be the new leaders.

Question:

**What would be a likely method where a US president+family+deputies could initiate and survive a thermonuclear exchange and govern afterwards?**

Edit: Removed question on prevention, and made the question more impersonal.

Comment: Interesting question, but would you be able to spit this Question so that there's only one question per Question? Also be careful to avoid asking questions about actions of individual characters, which your first question is possibly bordering on. Thanks

Comment: I am confident there is already a protocol for protecting the President and family in the event of a nuclear strike or attack.    As for post war they are only leaders of a few people.

Comment: Your president would be the leader of exactly nothing. The southern nations will survive the exchange relatively unharmed and will inherit the earth.

Comment: Part of the plan could be to point some of the nukes to the southern nations' military installations

Comment: Targeting non-nuclear non-threatening powers may prove to be tricky, a lot of people need to be in the conspiracy... And you know what happens when a lot of people know a secret.

Comment: Another possibility is Russian/Chinese targeting of those states in retaliatory strikes. Australia for example: http://www.smh.com.au/federal-politics/political-news/secrets-out-soviets-did-not-target-cities-20120805-23ny1.html

Comment: I'm not sure that such a place exists, in the long term. If you get a nuclear war going, you're going to run into nuclear winter across the entire globe no matter where those nukes land. Good luck growing anything under five years of skies filled with ash; not enough sunlight to really grow crops, much colder besides. This is the sort of thing generally believed to have killed off the dinosaurs (there caused by a massive asteroid impact) and this would have radioactive dust as well. The president might survive, but there won't be a country left to rule over.

Comment: According to some of my friends we should find out within the next year :P

Comment: No matter what he won't be president.  People don't forget a small think like thermonuclear war or genocide.  Unless he can make it appear as if the other side strike first (which requires too many to be in on the conspiracy to not have the secret leak) he will be hated by everyone who survives, and with the destruction the US (if on par with the sort of distraction required to 'wipe out his enemy') there won't be an infrastructure to force people to listen to him.  His previous status means nothing, he is a hated war criminal now to most people.

Answer (score 5):

There have been a couple of close calls during the Cold War (e.g. [1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_close_calls#1970s) and [1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Soviet_nuclear_false_alarm_incident)). They were prevented by officers who questioned the data on their screens.

So how to trigger a crisis and push it over the edge?

- Create an international crisis. The staff of the strategic forces should feel on edge. Send of some tweets which belittle the Russian president, order the Air Force to enforce a no fly zone over Syria, etc. Order DEFCON raised to 2.
- Create an attack warning. Since solar flares and computer errors are hard to simulate, how about intelligence warning about a bomb smuggling operation?
- Start moving to "an undisclosed location" and then order the "preemptive" strike.

Comment: +1. Any thoughts on how the president could live/govern after engineering such crisis?

Answer (score 3):

It's highly speculative about whether or not the president can do it. Some will say he can, and some will say he won't. Technically, the two man rule is in place (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-man_rule) where the president needs someone else to help him launch.

But you can always say that the "authority of the president" forced people to launch weapons. On top of that, there is a [bunker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Emergency_Operations_Center) for all presidents that they can use in case of nuclear war.

So to answer your question, with a few loyal deputies and pulling the strings in the right places, the president could easily launch a nuclear war and be completely fine.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article you linked: "The two man rule only applies in the missile silos and submarines; there is no check on the president's sole authority to order a nuclear launch."  The idea that an underling might disobey orders is a very different concept than the two man rule.

Answer (score 1):

"of which, the president and his family/deputies would be the new leaders"

The chances of this happening are not 100%. An alternative form of government if any gov at all will probably replace the current systems everywhere in the world.